# get value from row in html and use it in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a jsp with a table like this:

```
 <table style="width:100%">
   <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Adress</th>
     <tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    //here is a loop filling the table
     <tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
       <div>
          <td>${id}</td>
          <td>${name}</td>
          <td>${adress}</td>
       </div>
     <tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

So I want to use the id from the table in the modal (it's a popup dialog) for getting some information, but I can't get the value of the row that the user is pressing.
Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using javascript to do that. You can add `onclick` event to your div, where the row's ID is passed as argument to javascript function. And that function and open the modal dialog then.

```
<div onclick="openPopup(${id})">
```